# Creating differently named data frames in a for loop - Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop

I am working on creating a data frame for the data I have for each year (1971-2017). I have a for loop that creates the data frame, but it is all in one. How would I make it so that it creates a separate df for each year? Below is what I currently have.

```
for years in range(1971,2017):
        df = pd.read_csv('gene_%4.4d.txt'%years, sep='|', header=None, names=['PubMed ID','Title','Abstract','Affiliations','Pub Year','Pub Month','Pub Day','Journal'])
```

Comment: Read the entire csv into a single df then select sections from the df based on year. If you provide sample csv data, we can probably help with the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overwriting the `df` variable each time you read in a new file. To avoid this, I'd suggest initializing a list outside of the loop, and storing each new DataFrame in it:

```
all_dfs = []

for years in range(1971, 2017):
    df = pd.read_csv('gene_%4.4d.txt' % years, sep='|', header=None, names=['PubMed ID', 'Title', 'Abstract', 'Affiliations', 'Pub Year', 'Pub Month', 'Pub Day', 'Journal'])
    all_dfs.append(df)
```

Now `all_dfs` is a list of all the DataFrames. (A common thing to do next is to combine them all into one large DataFrame, e.g. `pd.concat(all_dfs)`)

Comment: Thank you. I didn't even think about how it was just writing over it. I'm just getting back into coding again and am trying to remember everything from before.